# Problem with doxygen and templates in .tpp file

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I have started using Doxygen (precompiled 1.8.14) to generate simple code documentation for my C++ project on Windows 10.

In a header file I define three templated functions and my definitions are placed in a .tpp file included at the end of the header file. Looking at the generated output, it seems doxygen does not read this file. <strike>Thus I concluded doxygen does not support this</strike>.

[image: The resulting Doxygen output]

However according to the manual (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html) it says that "Any other extension is parsed as if it is a C/C++ file." Is this sort of feature indeed not implemented?

IPC.hpp (sample)

```
class IPC {
public:
    template <class T, int N>
    bool setData(std::vector<T> data, Offsets offset);

    template <class T, int N>
    std::array<T, N> getData(Offsets offset);

    template <class T, int N>
    bool getData(std::array<T, N> &data, Offsets offset);

    bool getTrigger(Offsets selector, long timeout_ms = 0);
    void setTrigger(Offsets selector, Status on);
};

#include "IPC.tpp"
```

IPC.tpp (sample)

```
#pragma once
/*! Writes to the shared memory object.

    \param data gives the data that will be written.
    \param offset gives the byte offset from the start of the file.

    \return bool: true on completion

    \sa getData()
*/
template <class T, int N>
bool IPC::setData(std::vector<T> data, Offsets offset) {
    //Calculate the memory block size from the type and number
    unsigned int block_size = sizeof(T) * N;

    //Safety check
    if (block_size + offset > _size) {
        std::cerr << "Error at IPC::setData(): Block size is bigger than memory block size" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (data.size() < N) {
        std::cerr << "Error at IPC::setData(): Data array is smaller than N" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    //Create mapped_region
    mapped_region region(_shm, read_write, offset, block_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::memcpy((char* ) region.get_address() + sizeof(T) * i, &(data.at(i)), sizeof(T));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The mentioned  sentence is probably not accurate anymore. Did you add the `tpp` extension to `FILE_PATTERNS`? Also set the mapping of the `tpp` with `EXTENSION_MAPPING`

Comment: @albert i used the doxywizard GUI, is that setting in the Doxyfile?

Comment: Those are settings in the Doxyfile, but can be reached in the doxywizard as well in the `expert` tab and in the sub item `input` and `project`.

Comment: @albert that did the trick!

Comment: A better description will be in the documentation of the 1.8.15 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: add `tpp=C++` to `EXTENSION_MAPPING` (under `expert/project` in doxywizard) and `*.tpp` to `FILE_PATTERNS` (under `expert/input` in doxywizard).

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't worked for me yet. I have a couple of headers in the dependency graphs that show up as absolute paths for some reason - there's nothing different about the input - but this usually happens to x.hpp when x.tpp exists. (I immediately found a counterexample, but it's a trend at least.) Neither filename is a link in the dependency graph or is in the linked include section of the reference, and no dependency is shown from even x.tpp to x.hpp in the graph. Any ideas? Thanks!